# Google Map API Autocomplete. No dropdown list

Tags: javascript, api, dropdown

Some time ago this stopped producing the dropdown location list. What do I need to change please? Has something else been deprecated?

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[mykey]&sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       .
       .
       infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
       geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
       input = document.getElementById('address');
       var adOptions = {
           types: ['geocode']
       };
       autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, adOptions);
       google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
         infowindow.close(); 
         var place = autocomplete.getPlace(); 
         .
         .
         }
         document.getElementById('address').focus();
         .
        </script>
     </head>
   <body>
   <div><input id="address" type="text" value="" onfocus="this.value='Enter location'"></div>
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Do you have errors in console ?

Comment: check your browser console for errors..

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener missing closing parentheses, also check if  your key is expired or not, check console for errors and warning.

Comment: I get this error: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MyKey>&sensor=false&libraries=places" but it has not expired, as far as I know.

Comment: Adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> suppress the error but still no dropdown.